# What is the difference between DataTables and TableTools plug-in?

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I know TableTools is plug-in of DataTables and DataTables is plug-in of jQuery. Both provides common functionality such as copy, export an print.

Then what is the difference between them? When one should use one over another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableTools is extension of DataTable. DataTable Extensions are basically used to enhance the functionality of DataTable plugin like now we have [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/), [RowGroup](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/)  extensions. You can find more extensions [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/index).

Both DataTable and its Extensions use JQuery for their implementation. Only difference between them is [DataTable Extensions](https://datatables.net/extensions/index) only work with DataTable.

> [**TableTools**](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/)
>    which adds a highly customisable button toolbar to a DataTable.
>
> Key features include:
>
> 1. Copy to clipboard
> 2. Save table data as CSV, XLS or PDF files
> 3. Print view for clean printing
> 4. Row selection options
> 5. Easy use predefined buttons
> 6. Simple customisation of buttons
> 7. Well defined API for advanced control

But It is retired and its documentation is available at [Legacy DataTable](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)

> This extension has now been retired and has been replaced by the [Buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) and [Select](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) extensions. The documentation is retained for legacy reference only. New projects should use Buttons and Select in preference to TableTools.

[Source](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/)